# Missing the 5th key fragment of Fairel's Tomb

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is it possible to sell one of the key fragments? I've been through the five prerequisite tombs, several times, and definitely missed nothing. I've even tried selling one of the four I have to see if it's possible to sell, but I can't find them in my inventory! What did I do? How do I find a fifth key that I've already found, but somehow misplaced?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you went through the five prerequisite tombs? You might be counting the westernmost cave symbol as a tomb when it's not; it's a ruin and is not part of the quest.

Here are the locations of the five tombs housing Fairel's Tomb key fragments:

[image]

As I said, the westernmost cave symbol depicts a ruin and the easternmost is Fairel's Tomb proper.

Comment: Thanks Kareen. Those are the tombs I've been in, w the tourch lighting. I'm baffled at this point. 

Comment: Even the one at the bottom left? The one with the torches that are outside on scattered pillars? It took me *forever* to find that one.

Comment: Even that one:) Went so far as to draw my own so I could physically cross each off.lol. I'm new w x box one. Can there be glitches? I've had some weird stuff happen. Like jump up rock slide down and be on other end of map!

Comment: I don't know, I suppose it could be a glitch. Is the quest updated past the "find the five key fragments" in your journal?

Answer (score -1):

Been through all the tombs 3x's now and there is no 5th key. Found a bunch of statuettes but there are no key fragments left to claim. Glitchy game.